# What is the authenticated uesr's role - Java

Tags: java, roles, user-permissions

Good morning
I am using ejb2 (older application) on weblogic 10.

There are methods in my session beans that are secured to be executed by certain role.
Each of my ejb interface method I annotate with

```
 `@ejb.permission role-name="role1, role2"`
```

Since some methods maybe executed by users in few different roles, how can I tell which role runs the method?

I know how to know if a "caller is in a certain role"

```
Principal principal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal() ;
boolean isRole =  ctx.isCallerInRole("role2") ;
```

But, is there a way to obtain the actual caller's role?  Something like "getCallerRole()" or such?

In the xml file "ejb-security-roles.xml" I specify what roles are in application domain

```
<security-role>
 <role-name>role1</role-name>
 <role-name>role2</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Then, each of those roles are mapped to LDAP in the "weblogic-security-role-assignment.xml"

```
<security-role-assignment>
  <role-name>role1</role-name>
  <principal-name>Role1User</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment> 
<security-role-assignment>
  <role-name>role2</role-name>
  <principal-name>Role2User</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>`
```

Can anyone help, directing me to the right path of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `if (ctx.isCallerInRole("role2")) {`

According to Oracle  [Accessing an Enterprise Bean Caller’s Security Context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbyn/index.html),
it is only way to check user's role.

Comment: The problem is that eventually there can be more roles added, ... like, not 2 or 3, but .. 10-12.  Code will grow cluttered ... I need to access those roles in order to write to a database column - kind of like incident creation :(

Comment: yes, i understand, you should consider to use other security management library. for example spring-security https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Comment: Yea, well .. that would be for the future migration and updates project.  I suppose, I can deal with checking that isCallerInRole() way for a few roles that I have now